# How to make a byte arrary by looking at the header offsets using ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, bytebuffer

I need to make one byte array for my headers by following the below header offsets format.

```
// below is the header offsets

// m_off_addressed_center must be the first byte
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_addressed_center           = 0;
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_record_version             = m_off_addressed_center + 1;
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_num_records                = m_off_record_version + 1;
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_buffer_used                = m_off_num_records + sizeof(uint32_t);
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_address                    = m_off_buffer_used + sizeof(uint32_t);
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_address_from               = m_off_address + sizeof(CustomerAddress);
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_records_partition          = m_off_address_from + sizeof(CustomerAddress);
static constexpr uint32_t  m_off_already_replicated         = m_off_records_partition + 1;

// this is the full size of the header
static constexpr uint32_t m_head_offset = m_off_already_replicated + 1;
```

And `CustomerAddress` is a typedef for `uint64_t` and it is made up like this -

```
typedef uint64_t   CustomerAddress;

void client_data(uint8_t datacenter, 
                  uint16_t client_id, 
                  uint8_t data_id, 
                  uint32_t data_counter,
                  CustomerAddress& customer_address)
{
    customer_address = (uint64_t(datacenter) << 56)
                    + (uint64_t(client_id) << 40)
                    + (uint64_t(data_id) << 32)
                    + data_counter;
}
```

Below is what I have started and I am not sure whether I got everything right?

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(256 * 256); // allocating 64k buffer
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

// header layout
int m_off_addressed_center = 1;
int m_off_record_version = 2;
int m_off_num_records = 1;
int m_off_buffer_used = 100;

long m_off_address = client_data((byte) 10, (short) 12, (byte) 30, 200);
long m_off_address_from = client_data((byte) 20, (short) 22, (byte) 40, 150);

int m_off_records_partition = 10;
int m_off_already_replicated = 20;

b.putInt(m_off_addressed_center);
b.putInt(m_off_record_version);
b.putInt(m_off_num_records);
b.putInt(m_off_buffer_used);

b.putLong(m_off_address);
b.putLong(m_off_address_from);  

b.putInt(m_off_records_partition);
b.putInt(m_off_already_replicated);

byte[] result = b.array();
System.out.println(result);
```

And below is my method `client_data`

```
private static long client_data(byte datacenter, short client_id, byte data_id, int data_counter) {
    return ((long) (datacenter) << 56) | ((long) client_id << 40) | ((long) data_id << 32) | ((long) data_counter);
}
```

Does I got everything right basis on the header offset I have defined above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Your `records_partition` and `already_replicated` values are using `int` when they should be using `byte` instead.

```
private static long client_data(byte datacenter, short client_id, byte data_id, int data_counter)
{
    return (((long) datacenter) << 56) |
           (((long) client_id) << 40) |
           (((long) data_id) << 32) |
            ((long) data_counter);
}
```

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(28);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

// header layout
byte addressed_center = 1;
byte record_version = 2;
int num_records = 1;
int buffer_used = 100;
long address = client_data((byte) 10, (short) 12, (byte) 30, (in) 200);
long address_from = client_data((byte) 20, (short) 22, (byte) 40, (int) 150);
byte records_partition = 10;
byte already_replicated = 20;

b.put(     addressed_center);
b.put(     record_version);
b.putInt(  num_records);
b.putInt(  buffer_used);
b.putLong( address);
b.putLong( address_from);
b.put(     records_partition);
b.put(     already_replicated);

byte[] result = b.array();
System.out.println(result);
```

Alternatively:

```
private final static int m_off_addressed_center           = 0;
private final static int m_off_record_version             = m_off_addressed_center + 1;
private final static int m_off_num_records                = m_off_record_version + 1;
private final static int m_off_buffer_used                = m_off_num_records + 4;
private final static int m_off_address                    = m_off_buffer_used + 4;
private final static int m_off_address_from               = m_off_address + 8;
private final static int m_off_records_partition          = m_off_address_from + 8;
private final static int m_off_already_replicated         = m_off_records_partition + 1;

private final static int m_head_offset = m_off_already_replicated + 1;
```

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(m_head_offset);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

// header layout
byte addressed_center = 1;
byte record_version = 2;
int num_records = 1;
int buffer_used = 100;
long address = client_data((byte) 10, (short) 12, (byte) 30, (in) 200);
long address_from = client_data((byte) 20, (short) 22, (byte) 40, (int) 150);
byte records_partition = 10;
byte already_replicated = 20;

b.put(     m_off_addressed_center,   addressed_center);
b.put(     m_off_record_version,     record_version);
b.putInt(  m_off_num_records,        num_records);
b.putInt(  m_off_buffer_used,        buffer_used);
b.putLong( m_off_address,            address);
b.putLong( m_off_address_from,       address_from);
b.put(     m_off_records_partition,  records_partition);
b.put(     m_off_already_replicated, already_replicated);

byte[] result = b.array();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy. I tried your suggestion. As soon as I am using `client_data` method you provided me, it gives me compilation error -  `The method client_data(byte, short, byte, int) in the type ByteTest is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int)` Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I was hoping Java was smart enough to allow passing numeric literals to parameters and it would figure out the correct data types to use. I guess not. I updated my examples to use type casts.

Comment: Thanks for edit. Can you explain what is the difference between two solutions you provided. It looks same to me, it is just that second oone has two parameters in the put method.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), it tells you what the difference is.